# Why is this Clojure program so slow? How to make it run fast?

Tags: java, performance, scala, clojure

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216888/is-nodejs-faster-than-clojure) it is clearly explained how to optimize a Clojure program dealing with primitive values: use type annotations and unchecked math, and it will run fast:

```
(set! *unchecked-math* true)

(defn add-up ^long [^long n]
  (loop [n n i 0 sum 0]
    (if (< n i)
      sum
      (recur n (inc i) (+ i sum)))))
```

So, just out of curiosity, I've tried it in `lein repl` and, to my surprise, found this code running ~20 times slower that expected (Clojure 1.6.0 on Oracle JDK 1.8.0_11 x64):

```
user=> (time (add-up 1e8))
"Elapsed time: 2719.188432 msecs"
5000000050000000
```

Equivalent code in Scala 2.10.4 (same JVM) runs in ~90ms:

```
def addup(n: Long) = { 
  @annotation.tailrec def sum(s: Long, i: Long): Long = 
    if (i == 0) s else sum(s + i, i - 1)
  sum(0, n)
}
```

So, what am I missing in the Clojure code sample? Why is it so slow (should theoretically be roughly the same speed)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Benchmarking with `lein repl` is generally a bad idea as it specifically sets non-server JVM settings. Using the Clojure JAR directly I see ~40ms on a 3.5ghz i7 iMac running JDK 8 under OS X 10.9.

Comment: I added `:jvm-opts ^:replace []` to my `project.clj` and the exec time dropped to 80ms. Thanks! Found the trick here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902479/clojure-performance-repl-versus-uberjar

Answer (score 5):

Further to [@dnolen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005603/1562315), a few observations:

Though it turns out to make no real difference, we should make the Clojure function the same shape as the Scala one. In

```
(defn add-up ^long [^long n]
  (loop [n n i 0 sum 0]
    (if (< n i)
      sum
      (recur n (inc i) (+ i sum)))))
```

- `n` is not changed by the `recur`, so need not be bound in the
  `loop`.
- The two remaining arguments are in the opposite order to the Scala function.
- It runs up the numbers, whereas the Scala runs down.

Mending these inconsistencies, we get

```
defn add-up [^long n]
  (loop [sum 0, i n]
    (if (zero? i)
      sum
      (recur (+ sum i) (dec i)))))
```

(The Scala type system ensures that the argument `n` is converted to a `Long` on call. As I understand it (please correct me if I'm wrong), the Clojure `^long` type hint promises to treat a `Long` argument well, but does not promise to convert a `Double` like `1e8` to a `Long`. But I got very inconsistent results when I made the corresponding changes.)

On my laptop, the above gives

```
(time (add-up 100000000))
"Elapsed time: 103.636782 msecs"
5000000050000000
```

If you remove the type hint

```
(defn add-up [n]
  ...
  )
```

... the elapsed time multiplies by about twenty:

```
(time (add-up 100000000))
"Elapsed time: 2374.399915 msecs"
5000000050000000
```

- This has more effect than removing unchecked math, which roughly
  triples the elapsed time.
- Type hinting the return type has no discernible effect.

All this on Clojure 1.5.0 on OpenJDK Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

On a three year-old mac book, I get the following:

```
(time (add-up 1e8))
 "Elapsed time: 68.536 msecs"
```

and

```
(time (add-up 1e9))
 "Elapsed time: 771.157 msecs"
  => 500000000500000000
```

What would be the version of Lein you are using, can you check the clojure Version with:

```
(clojure-version)
```

Comment: that's `"1.6.0"`, as one would expect from Clojure 1.6.0 :)

Comment: was trying to figure out if it was picking up a different version somehow. What your version of Leiningen then ?

Comment: it's leiningen-2.3.4
Thanks for trying to help.